# my ShinyApp is failing to start when I try to run it on shinyapps.io although there is no problem running it locally?

Tags: r, shiny, error-handling, gzip, fread

I get the following message when I run my app:

"An error has occurred
The application failed to start. Contact the author for more information"

I looked at the logs and there is no error there, it stops once a big file is being read.
I have a large .csv file (around 800MB, of 36 million rows) which I compressed to .gz and is now ~200 MB and I am reading it with the fread function in the app. I am asking for help regarding these two points:

1- Is there any better way to deal with a large .csv file if it is causing the issue?
2- Is there any other way I could check the culprit error other than the logs on shinyapps.io?

I tried CNT+SHIFT+J and I got the following errors:

- TypeError: (destructured parameter) is undefined
- sendRemoveListener on closed conduit 87677a2c52b84ad3a151a4a72f5bd3c4@jetpack.30374008717367

I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you installed the `R.utils` package? That is needed to read .gz-files with `data.table::fread()`.

Comment: @jpiversen yes I have and I made sure it was read in logs
(i.e Attaching package: ‘R.utils’)